# Which class implements the spring roo repository interface

Tags: spring, jpa, configuration, repository, spring-roo

I am new to spring roo, and now, I am building a small project using spring roo 1.2.0.M1, and I fins=d that when I create a jpa repository using `repository jpa`, I only see the interface has been created, but I cannot find the class which implements that interface.

Another thing is I want to add @PersistenceContext to repository to specify which persistence context it should use. Because I cannot find the implement class, I cannot find out a way to do this.

If someone knows how to do this, please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like roo uses [Spring Data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) which works exactly that way: you define an interface using fixed name conventions, and at runtime the implementation proxy is generated for you based on the method name and return type (similar to the scaffolding approach of rails / grails).

Here's blog post that explains the mechanism:

> [GETTING STARTED WITH SPRING DATA JPA](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/)

Comment: Spring Roo (as of 1.1.5 and I think 1.2.1) does not use Spring Data JPA. Spring Roo does compile time code generation through AspectJ to generate the scaffolding. Spring Data JPA does it through runtime code generation through proxies (I believe cglib).